# Create a Group in Microsoft Graph API with a Owner

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a Office 365 Group that I would like to add through the Microsoft Graph API. Based on the API documentation, I believe I need

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 244
```

```json
{
  "description": "Self help community for library",
  "displayName": "Library Assist",
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "library",
  "securityEnabled": false
}
```

But when I try to add

```json
"owner": [{ "@odata.id": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"}]
```

I get an error (The id is really an id that exists in the office so I don't want to put it here).

They work if I first run the create group and then the add owner but not together. Why?

Would like to make it as easy for me as possible. I'm putting postman in the tags just because that's the tools I'm currently using

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually this is supported and possible today using OData bind syntax (i.e. your syntax is incorrect). NOTE: This is our bad, not your, because we haven't documented this supported behavior.  I'll file a bug on our side to document this.

In the meantime, try adding this to your request (it worked for me), and let us know if this works for you:

`"owners@odata.bind": ["https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}"]`

In fact, in the same request you can also bind members as part of the request:

`"owners@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id1}"
  ],
  "members@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id1}",
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id2}"
  ]`

Not sure what the limits are on the number of items you can put in the binding collection, but I'm sure there is one.  I'll see if one of the devs can comment on this.

Hope this helps,

Comment: This helps! Thanks! It feels much better to create the group with the owners and members already stated!

Comment: may I ask one more question? I was wondering if I could remove the notification to new members? (this is in a testing phase so I don't want to bother other co-workers)

Comment: Not currently, but it is something we are working on.

Comment: If anyone at MS sees this, can you please add `owners` (as well as an example of a valid property value) to the listed properties of a `group` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/group?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).  there is a warning [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#request-body) about not creating groups without owners, so it would be helpful if the docs could describe how to do this.  thank you.

Comment: ah, just saw there is example of creating group with owner [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-post-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#example-2-create-a-group-with-owners-and-members) and it still uses the same syntax as was defined in the above answer.  thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Dan, thank you for this solution! Based on it I created solution which works also with Graph API. The trick is to use the following class which inherits Group from Graph client lib:

```cs
public class GroupExtended : Group
{
    [JsonProperty("owners@odata.bind", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string[] OwnersODataBind { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("members@odata.bind", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string[] MembersODataBind { get; set; }
}
```

and then add it like that:

```cs
var newGroup = new GroupExtended
{
    DisplayName = displayName,
    Description = description,
    MailNickname = mailNickname,
    MailEnabled = true,
    SecurityEnabled = false,
    Visibility = isPrivate == true ? "Private" : "Public",
    GroupTypes = new List<string> { "Unified" }
};

if (owners != null && owners.Length > 0)
{
    var users = GetUsers(graphClient, owners);
    if (users != null)
    {
        newGroup.OwnersODataBind = users.Select(u => string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}", u.Id)).ToArray();
    }
}

if (members != null && members.Length > 0)
{
    var users = GetUsers(graphClient, members);
    if (users != null)
    {
        newGroup.MembersODataBind = users.Select(u => string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{0}", u.Id)).ToArray();
    }
}

await graphClient.Groups.Request().AddAsync(newGroup);
```

Whole solution is described here: http://sadomovalex.blogspot.com/2018/11/create-azure-ad-groups-with-initial.html.