# Add group members when creating a group (msgraph-sdk-java)

Tags: java, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I would like to add members to a group at group creation time. How can I achieve that?

The request:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "displayName": "displayName",
  "mailEnabled": true,
  "mailNickname": "mailNickname",
  "securityEnabled": false,
  "groupTypes": [
    "Unified"
  ],
  "members@odata.bind": [
    "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{userId}"
  ]
}
```

And the code:

```
Group group = new Group();

group.displayName = "displayName";  
group.mailEnabled = true;
group.mailNickname = "mailNickname";
group.securityEnabled = false;    
List<String> groupTypes = new ArrayList<>();
groupTypes.add("Unified");
group.groupTypes=groupTypes;
String userId = "userId";   

//HERE add members to group
//group.members=???

serviceClient.groups().buildRequest().post(group);
```

How and where should I write the "members@odata.bind" part?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a Group in Microsoft Graph API with a Owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467617/create-a-group-in-microsoft-graph-api-with-a-owner)

Comment: @MohitVerma-MSFT Yes, it's a bit similar question, but I am asking help for java sdk not for dot-net sdk.

Answer (score 0):

One options to specify members would be to construct *a custom query*:

```
JsonObject groupPayload = new JsonObject();
groupPayload.addProperty("displayName","<value>");
groupPayload.addProperty("mailNickname","<value>");
groupPayload.addProperty("mailEnabled",true);
groupPayload.addProperty("securityEnabled",false);
JsonArray groupTypes = new JsonArray();
groupTypes.add("Unified");
groupPayload.add("groupTypes",groupTypes);

//specify members
JsonArray members = new JsonArray();
members.add(String.format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/%s",userId));
groupPayload.add("members@odata.bind",members);

JsonObject response  = graphClient.customRequest("/groups").buildRequest().post(groupPayload).getAsJsonObject();
```